# Django and docker-compose serving with NGINX: file not found

Tags: django, docker, nginx

I've been trying to set up my django project with gunicorn and nginx.  The server runs, but I've been struggling to get the admin page to serve static files (I haven't created any other static files for the project, so I'm just starting with admin).

I bit the bullet and just copied the original django admin static file into my own project, but when I load the admin page, there are no static files.  My docker "web" image shows:

```
web_image_name | Not Found: /static/admin/js/...
web_image_name | Not Found: /static/admin/css/...
...
```

This error is interesting, since when I go into that image's terminal and do "ls", I can see the static directory.

Is this problem related to nginx, docker, or both?

**Code:**

nginx.conf:

```
# nginx.conf

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name your_domain.com;  # Change to your domain or IP address

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://web:8000;  # Points to your Gunicorn service
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

        location /static/ {
            alias /app/static/;
        }
    }
}
```

docker-compose.yml (truncated):

```
version: "3"

services:

  web:
    container_name: newspigeon_web
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: >
      bash -c "python manage.py migrate && gunicorn --workers=4 --bind=0.0.0.0:8000 newspigeon.wsgi:application"
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    env_file:
      - ./.env.dev
    volumes:
      - .:/newspigeon
      - static_files:/newspigeon/static
    networks:
      - newspigeon_default

  nginx:
    container_name: newspigeon_nginx
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - web
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf  # Mount your Nginx configuration file
      - static_files:/app/static
    links:
      - web:web  # Link the Nginx service to the web service
    networks:
      - newspigeon_default

volumes:
  static_files:
```

DockerFile:

```
# Use the official Python image as base
FROM python:3.9

# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the requirements file to the container
COPY requirements.txt /app/

# Install the dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt


RUN mkdir -p /app/newspigeon/static

# Copy the rest of the application code to the container
COPY . /app/

# Collect static files for nginx
RUN python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
# Expose the port your application runs on
EXPOSE 8000

# Start the application
CMD ["gunicorn", "--workers=4", "--bind=0.0.0.0:8000", "newspigeon.wsgi:application"]
```

and the /static/ folder is in the root directory of the django project.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Place `location /static/` above `location /`.

Comment: @Macro Still having the same issue :(.  I'm guessing that it might be an nginx error at this point.

Comment: Try using `root` in your directive instead of alias. If your static folder is at `/opt/myapp/static/`, then use `root /opt/myapp;` in the directive.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Marco.  I still haven't gotten it to work, so I'm just going to start over with nginx and try to be more methodical.  Hopefully, I'll find what I'm doing wring that way.